# how to send phpmail with html body?

Tags: php, phpmailer, html-email

when i am using simple text body in mail it's working good but when i am trying to send html mail it's not working.

bellow my both scripts please check both script..

**Simple Body Mail Working Fine**

```
 $mailto="xyz@gmail.com";  //Enter recipient email address here

 $subject = "Email Confirm";

 $from="no-reply@example.com>";          //Your valid email address here

 $message_body = 'You Have an Mail';

       mail($mailto,$subject,$message_body,"From:".$from);

       echo "Your email has been sent successfully";
```

**Html body Mail Not Working**

```
 $mailto="xyz@gmail.com";  //Enter recipient email address here

       $subject = "Email Confirm";

       $from="no-reply@example.com";          //Your valid email address here

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
 
// Create email headers
$headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


       $message_body = '
       <html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Welcome to CodexWorld</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <h1>Thanks you for joining with us!</h1> 
        <table cellspacing="0" style="border: 2px dashed #FB4314; width: 100%;"> 
            <tr> 
                <th>Name:</th><td>CodexWorld</td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr style="background-color: #e0e0e0;"> 
                <th>Email:</th><td>contact@codexworld.com</td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <th>Website:</th><td><a href="http://www.codexworld.com">www.codexworld.com</a></td> 
            </tr> 
        </table> 
    </body> 
    </html>';

       mail($mailto,$subject,$message_body, $headers,"From:".$from);

       echo "Your email has been sent successfully";
```

Comment: Is there some error/warning message when the code runs? or is it that the code runs without error but the mail is not recieved by recipient?

Comment: Please check the output of the mail function to determine if the call has succeeded or failed. See example at https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-send-email.php

Comment: You don't say how it's "not working", so we can't really help. Since you tagged your question with [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), how about actually using it? It deals with all the low-level formatting of email for you so you don't have silly problems like these.